Extension of a Hölder function on the product space
Let $k\geq0, \alpha>0$ and let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^{k,\alpha}$ convex domain. Suppose $f:[0,1]\times \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following:

For each $t\in[0,1]$, $\mathcal{\Omega_t}:={\rm supp}(f(t,\cdot))$ is convex, $f(t,\cdot)>0$ on $\Omega_t$, and $f(t,\cdot): \Omega_t\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{k,\alpha}$; and
there exists $\partial_t f(t,\cdot)\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega_t)$ such that for $\delta$ small, $\left\|\frac{f(t+h,\cdot) - f(t,\cdot)}{h}-\partial_tf_t\right\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\cap_{h<\delta}\Omega_{t+h})} \to 0$.

Given an open set $\Omega'$ containing $\Omega$. Can we extend $f$ to $[0,1]\times \Omega'$, say to $\tilde f$, such that the two properties above are preserved, in the sense that,

For each $t\in[0,1]$, $\tilde f>0$ on $\Omega'$, $\tilde f(t,\cdot): \Omega'\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{k,\alpha}$; and
there exists $\partial_t \tilde f(t,\cdot)\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega')$ such that for $\delta$ small, $\left\|\frac{\tilde f(t+h,\cdot) - \tilde f(t,\cdot)}{h}-\partial_t \tilde f_t\right\|_{C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega')} \to 0$.


Can you clarify what $\mathcal{U}$ is? It is a subset of $[0,1]\times\overline{\Omega}$ but then $f(t,\cdot)$ is well defined for all $t\in[0,1]$?

Thanks for your comment! I have modified the question. The picture looks like this: $f$ is supported on a smooth belt in $[0,1]\times \overline \Omega$ and $f$ is both time and space regular. I would like to extend $f$ to the whole space $[0,1]\times \overline{\Omega}$ while preserving its time and space regualrity.

The setting in the question may not be the most precise that captures the picture. Some insights and suggestions in formulating the problem will also be appreciated!
